ERROR ~ No such variable: input_file in Nextflow
I've started to learn Nextflow and I'm trying to apply Manuel's practice, but I'm encountering an error at the first step of this seemingly simple pipeline.
Thanks for your help
The Code:
`#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.input_file = params.input_file ?: 'example.txt'

input_file_channel = Channel.fromPath(params.input_file)

process catFile {
    input:
    path input_file from input_file_channel  

    script:
    """
    cat ${input_file}
    """
}

workflow {
    catFile()
}`

Error:
`ERROR ~ No such variable: input_file

 -- Check script 'main.nf' at line: 9 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details`


Where did you see the "path from" syntax?  If there's not more than one file, why not use path input_file, name: params.input_file?

@TimRoberts This is just the older DSL1 syntax.

Nextflow now uses DSL2 syntax by default, which enables channel forking. This means we no longer require the from and into operators. Your example simply becomes:
params.input_file = 'example.txt'


process catFile {

    debug true

    input:
    path input_file

    script:
    """
    cat ${input_file}
    """
}

workflow {

    input_file_channel = Channel.fromPath( params.input_file )

    catFile( input_file_channel )
}

